# could not convert string to float 12 + 13

Tags: python, valueerror

I am trying to write a very simple code which I will feed it two numbers (with the *input* function) and it'll give me a result based on these numbers. When the numbers are *just* numbers (e.g., 12 or 15) everything works fine, but when instead of a number is, for example, an addition (i.e., 6 + 6) then I get an error saying "could not convert string to float: '6 + 6'.

Please see below a reproducible example:

```
def calc_sal(number1, number2):
    return number1 * 4.5 + number2

number1 = float(input("Give number1 "))
number2 = float(input("Give number2 "))

print(calc_sal(number1, number2))
```

and this is the error:

```
Give number1 6 + 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SalaryCalc.py", line 4, in <module>
    number1 = float(input("Give number1 "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6 + 6'
```

It appears to me that I cannot perform an addition through the *input* function, instead it thinks that it's a string "6 + 6". However, when I am running the same code line by line in an interactive session, everything works just fine (i.e., when the input is 6 + 6, the output is 12, rather than "6 + 6").
So do you why is this happening only when I am running the programme through the terminal and not interactively? And how to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: `6 + 6` is not a single number…

Comment: How do you input the values?[6 <enter> 6] or 6 + 6 enter?

Comment: Related question (about how to evaluate input that needs to be calculated first): [ValueError: malformed string when using ast.literal_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20748202/216074)

Comment: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6 + 6'`

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on who is going to use this code:

- If it's only you, you could use the `eval` funciton:

  ```
  >>> eval('6+6')
  12
  ```
- If you're going to let someone else enter numbers, `eval` is evil. It can format your hard drive if malicious code is entered! (see also [How harmful is eval](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html))

  Consider other possibilities like `ast.literal_eval` (only for `+` and `-`, even `*` is too hard for it), [`pyparsing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string/2371789#2371789) (powerful,
  but requires writing a program for this)
  , etc

You could also consider `numexpr` library (installs `numpy` as a requirement and returns numpy array as a result):

```
>>> import numexpr as ne
>>> ne.evaluate('6**2')
array(36, dtype=int32)
>>> print(ne.evaluate('6**2'))
36
```

Comment: Any comments on downvote?

Comment: I imagine because suggesting `eval` to someone that doesn't yet know the difference between a Python expression in the interpreter and a string literal taken from the input (warning or not) is at best not helpful and at worst actually harmful...

Comment: Not my downvote, but I thought that `literal_eval` would be the weapon of choice to minimise dangers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698/8881141

Comment: @JonClements The most important thing In my answer is a note that it is harmful. If OP finds this function himself he might not realize how harmful it is. On the other hand if OP doesn't find an answer to a question that simple he might lose interest in python in general. `eval` is a function present in all interpreted languages and I see no harm in _knowing_ about it.

Comment: @Piinthesky `literal_eval` only does **literals** - it doesn't do expressions...

Comment: @JonClements I see. I just tried it with the OP's example using addition and subtraction, which worked. On SO I have seen now [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2371789/8881141), how to parse mathematical expressions. Surely slightly more complicated than using `eval`.

Comment: @Piinthesky I would say negligeably ;)

Comment: I did some look-around with regards the potential dangers of the eval function, and I've been urged to use ast.literal_eval() as an alternative.

Many thanks for your replies.

Comment: Hmm.. Python has it's own solution for everything,,, I thought of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation anyways This answer is better +1 upvote from me. I guess some one downvoted so it is 0 still..,