# Graph Equation From Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to display a graph with a formula from the user using matplotlib in Python 3.6, but I'm having some problems. I tried

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graph(x_range):
    x = np.array(x_range)
    y = 2*x
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()

graph(range(-10, 11))
```

which works fine, but if I try replacing `y = 2*x` with `y = input()` and try inputting `2*x` in the terminal, I get an error stating `ValueError: Illegal format string "2*x"; two marker symbols`

Any ideas as to how to fix this error, or is there a better way to graph a equation given by the user?

Thanks

Comment: There is no easy way to do what you want in python/numpy. Perhaps Sympy can be used?

Comment: You'll have to build it. 
 Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748202/valueerror-malformed-string-when-using-ast-literal-eval

Comment: I just decided to do what @DyZ said and use Sympy instead. Seems to be working perfectly fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `y=2*x` with this

```
y = eval(input('Enter formula'))
```

However this is a very dirty shortcut.

Comment: Thou shalt never use and specifically advise to use `eval` or `exec`, as they are evil.

Comment: @DyZ evil prevails :s

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something fairly lightweight that "suits your situation" and doesn't evaluate "all mathematical expressions" then a whitelist method might serve you well

```
x = np.array(x_range)

print('equation types')
print('1) y=mx+b')
print('2) y=a*sin(b*(x+c))')
print('3) y=ax^2 + bx + c')
#...etc.

eq = int(input('equation type number: '))

if eq == 1:
    m = float(input('m'))
    b = float(input('b'))
    y = m*x+b
if eq == 2:
    #...etc.

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```