# Pandas ast.literal_eval crashes with non-basic datatypes while reading lists from csv

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas, nltk, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a Pandas dataframe that was saved as a csv by using command:

```
file.to_csv(filepath + name + ".csv", encoding='utf-8', sep=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

I know that while saving, all of the columns in the dataframe are converted to String format, but I've managed to convert them back using

```
raw_table['synset'] = raw_table['synset'].map(ast.literal_eval)
```

This seems to work fine when the lists in columns contain numbers or text, but not when there's a different datatype. Point in question comes as I try to open a column "synset" with following values (where every line represents a different row in column, and also empty lists are included):

```
[Synset('report.n.03')]
[]
[Synset('application.n.04')]
[]
[Synset('legal_profession.n.01')]
[Synset('demeanor.n.01')]
[Synset('demeanor.n.01')]
[Synset('outgrowth.n.01')]
```

These values come from nltk-package, and are Synset-objects.

Trying to evaluate these using ast.literal_eval() causes following crash:

```
File "/.../site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2158, in map
new_values = map_f(values, arg)
File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1574, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
File "/.../ast.py", line 85, in literal_eval
return _convert(node_or_string)
File "/.../ast.py", line 61, in _convert
return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
File "/.../ast.py", line 84, in _convert
raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7f1918146ac8>
```

Any help on how I could resolve this problem?

Comment: Believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20748308/2535611) helps, just extend that to `ast.Call` objs too

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) to read from the file?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh

I am opening the file using read_csv from Pandas:

    pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: malformed string when using ast.literal\_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748202/valueerror-malformed-string-when-using-ast-literal-eval)